# IPMI: SOL Hangning

Tags: linux, ipmi, ipmitool

I have IPMI configured on a Ubuntu server.

Currently, the power status is on, but I cannot access this remote appliance.

```
ipmitool -Ilan -H IP -UADMIN -P'password' chassis power status
Chassis Power is on
```

Pinging the IP from another remote appliance I receive:

```
"Destination Host Unreachable."
```

I've used IPMI to cycle and reset the power:

```
ipmitool -Ilan -H IP -UADMIN -P'!#letmein' chassis power reset
ipmitool -Ilan -H IP -UADMIN -P'!#letmein' chassis power cycle
```

I'm using linux and the server that I'm trying to access is linux (ubuntu to be exact).

I've tried ipmi sol it says:

```
[SOL Sesson operational.  Use ~? for help]
```

It appears to be hanging though, and I can't type anything.

Finally it updated me with:

```
Error sending SOL data: FAIL
Error: No response to keepalive - Terminating session
Error: No response de-activating SOL payload
```

So it appears there is some issue with sending SOL data.  I'm researching this further.

I changed the boot disk and it allowed me to select what distro I wan to load up.  However, when I select one I loose SOL it goes back to hanging.

Anyway I can send arp from grub?

Comment: What's on the server's boot screen?

Comment: @ewwhite I cannot see the boot screen. I'm remote. Can I use IPMI to access the boot screen?

Comment: I've fixed my question in hopes that I can have the negative mark removed.  This is a serious question.

Comment: @ewwhite I can access grub now, but when i select a distro is just hangs again.

Comment: @KirsKringle - might check your connection for lost packets, check if there's anything helpful in the SEL: `ipmitool sel elist last 10`, get some additional information using the `--debug` switch.

Comment: @7y7 Just old almost 8 months old temp readings... Did an MTR to the IPMI address and I'm getting no packet loss, but when trying to ping the actual appliance IP I get the error message in the question above.  Currently at 100 packets sent and 0% loss.

Comment: @KirsKringle Is SSH or HTTPS connection to the BMC working steadly ?  Check the BIOS `Redirection After Boot` parameter - it could redirect the console once the OS loads, try turning it off and retry connecting to the SOL.

Comment: @7y7 It was due to a mount error in fstab....  Still couldn't use IPMI to skip it.  I guess someone tried using the GUI of IPMI and they could do it... Quite disappointing. I wonder why it wasn't showing that in the command linethough... drives me nuts.

Comment: It would be _very helpful_ to post the specs to the system (motherboard or system brand/model.) BMCs have a long history of being very buggy, and knowing which quirks to dig into would help.  Also, the mixed information in your question are concerning - are you really getting a response from a remote IPMI?  If so, why is there no ping response? If there's no ping response, how did you do an mtr and have no loss?  BTW, was this ever resolved?